# SQL:How can I find unique date ranges from a given a set of date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table of users along with their date ranges in INT format(yyyymmdd) as below:

```
Id  Name    StartDate   EndDate
1   abc     20160216    20160217
1   abc     20160228    20160228
1   abc     20160301    20160301
1   abc     20160301    20160302
1   abc     20160301    20170401
1   abc     20160302    20160302
1   abc     20160303    20160303
1   abc     20160303    20170401
3   def     20160217    20160217
3   def     20160218    20160229
3   def     20160218    20160229
3   def     20160225    20160225
3   def     20160229    20160229
3   def     20160302    20160302
```

I need to find consecutive unique date ranges for every user(without any duplicates). The output should like this

```
 Id Name    StartDate   EndDate
1   abc     20160216    20160217
1   abc     20160228    20160228
1   abc     20160301    20170401
3   def     20160217    20160229
3   def     20160302    20160302
```

With this script you can create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(
 Id INT,
 Name VARCHAR(50),
 StartDate INT,
 EndDate INT,
)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160216,20160217)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160228,20160228)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160301,20160301)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160301,20160302)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160301,20170401)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160302,20160302)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160303,20160303)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'abc',20160303,20170401)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'def',20160217,20160217)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'def',20160218,20160229)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'def',20160218,20160229)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'def',20160225,20160225)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'def',20160229,20160229)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'def',20160302,20160302)
```

EDIT:
In Short, If I have data like this

```
Id  Name    StartDate   EndDate
1   abc     20160216    20160217
**1 abc     20160301    20160302
1   abc     20160301    20160303**
```

I need output like below.

```
Id  Name    StartDate   EndDate
1   abc     20160216    20160217
**1 abc     20160301    20160303**
```

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far in attempt to do this?

Comment: If I use a `select distinct` on this it returns a lot more thank your expected output. Looking at your input and what you want output wise, your question does not make sense. Please explain what "consecutive unique date ranges for every user" means to you by explaining your expected output or update your expected output to match what it would actually be given the sample data.

Comment: I edited my question. A user has two date ranges March1-March2 and March1-March3. I want only March1-March3 ,as March1-March2 is a part of March1-March3,

Answer (score 1):

Guess I you'll need to use `SELECT DISTINCT`, which searches only the unique values from the column of the table.

Is that what you're looking for? I didn't get exactly how do you want the output...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to concat StartDate and EndDate and look for the concated value to be distinct.

```
select id, StartDate, EndDate, distinct(contactDate) from (Select id, StartDate, EndDate, CONCAT_WS('', StartDate, EndDate) AS concatDate from Data)
```

**Edit**

Actually I think you can do it without concating as well...

```
Select id, StartDate, EndDate, distinct(StartDate, EndDate) from data
```

Comment: your syntax is incorrect for `distinct` in sql-server

Comment: No problem, just letting you know.